# how to run an admin task in joomla with a cron job?

Tags: joomla, cron

I wrote a custom component in Joomla! that pulls in content from an XML feed and stores it in the Joomla database. I want the admin URL (/administrator/index?option=com_mycomp) to run via cron once every night to run the component. I can't figure out how to make this work, though, since the component is an administrator task and you have to be logged in to run it.

How do I get by this? I tried including my user/pw in the url (http:admin:password@www.mysite.com/joomla/administrator....) but it doesn't work. Is there anyway other way to send login credentials, or any other way to do this?

Comment: you either need to write a php scfipt to log in and execute it or simply make it a frontend component with a hard coded password or HTTP_REFERER check

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I also am developping a component that needs to run at least once a day in order to sync with a db. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is very old, but here's how I handled a similar task.

The "trick" is to take the custom PHP code you have created, and embed it into an article within your Joomla website.

I did this by using the JUMI extension, that allows custom PHP code to be stored within the Joomla repository and embedded, as required, within an article.

Then, create a CRON task that will activate the appropriate URL for the page containing the code you want to run.

Comment: My turn to ask about this very old answer! Can you please advise what command you used to run the article.

Comment: See my updated answer, similar to Jumi but you can define exactly what the url you want to call is in Joomla

Answer (score 2):

Just put your script in the administrator directory of the component like

```
/administrator/components/com_yourcomponent/cron.yourcomponent.php
```

This is how [FeedGator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/automatic-articles/13573) handles cron tasks [Sounds very similar to what you're trying to do.] ... you can also write a frontend controller in your component per one of the comments

========== [Update] ============

I created [this ultra-simple installable component](https://github.com/idea34/com_show/archive/master.zip) that could also be used for this purpose. It allows for a frontend menu item to be assigned to a php page (including the route as suggested). So you:

1. install the component
2. create new menu item, (may want to use a ['hidden' menu](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-mar-2014/item/1790-using-hidden-menus)) select the 'show' view option and enter the script to run via cron in 'file to include' like path/yourcron.php
3. call the 'page' in your cron or test using: yourjoomlasite.com/index.php?option=com_show or yourjoomlasite.com/your-menu-alias

Answer (score 1):

Mostly corn urls works from front-end even if your component deals with administrator only in Joomla.
So whatever your code in admin cron get it to front-end & so that your cronurl becomes like index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=cronjob.
Use this url to set cron using cPanel.

However this solution doesn't need to see whether admin is logged or not.